# google chrome extension autostart & autoclose

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension which take care of my login details. But to make it work, I have to click on it to login and to logout. Is there any API or tweak through which it can do this automatically?? such that When I open the chrome, it automatically log into the websites and when i close the chrome, it logs out from those sites automatically.

Comment: Well, there's no reliable way to detect final quit event in Chrome *and* have time to do something so you'll have to press the button manually at least on exit.

Comment: What about [onRemoved](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove)? -> its callback object has the property `isWindowClosing` - Have you tried using that?